# jQuery validator: Call method added with addMethod

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How I can call a validate  method created with jQuery.validator?

Example:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("functionA", function(value, element) {
    if($.trim(value)==""){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, "MSG A");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("functionB", function(value, element) {
    return jQuery.functionA(); //<--- How do I do it?
}, "MSG B");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Methods added with `addMethod` are inside the `$.validator.methods` object.  You can call `functionA` like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("functionB", function(value, element) {
    return jQuery.validator.methods.functionA.call(this, value, element);
}, "MSG B");
```