# Validate collections on client-side in ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, client-side-validation

In my ASP MVC 5 app I have a model with an IEnumerable property, represented in the form as a list of checkboxes. I want to validate that at least one of them are selected. This is a simple thing in my mind but I can't get it to work. The validation works fine on the server side.

I have written an unobtrusive validator similar to this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('selectone', function (_, container) {
  // Check that at least one checkbox is checked.
  return $(container).has('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
})
```

But the problem is that there is no one field to attach it to, so it never gets run (I've checked in the debugger).

I've tried to add a dummy input which mimics ASP MVC's attributes (data-val=true, data-val-selectone=...), but I can't get the validator to run it.

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked in your other JS code if you're trying to prevent default. This might prevent the propagation of your events. OtherWise take alook at this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038423/jquery-validator-call-method-added-with-addmethod). It might help.

Comment: What is your server side validator? Does your validator implement `IClientValidatable`?

Comment: Yes it does, but since the server side validator operates on an IEnumerable, there is no automatic client side validation like there is with normal fields. At least, I haven't got it to work.